# Raising the Energy Bar in Beyond Earth

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I'm having problems in Civ Beyond Earth.

How does one raise the Energy and Science in Civ Beyond Earth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember to always use as many trade routes as you can, they bring a LOT of money

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Energy is the currency in Civ:BE.  It's represented by a yellow circle.  You'll earn it by:

- Establishing trade routes, especially with other Civs, but also frequently from stations
- Building certain tile improvements (generators from the start, but later nodes will also produce it, certain resources boost tile production of it)
- Creating buildings in your cities, mostly reactors
- Launching Solar Collector satellites over your territory/cities
- Certain virtues boost it, mainly those in the Industry tree
- Producing "Industry" in your cities will convert a portion that city's production to energy
- Stealing it via espionage from other civs.  This is one of the easiest espionage operations
- Establishing connections from your cities to the capital.  This can be either a water route or by land.

Energy is spent to maintain your units and buildings.  Thus, if your energy per turn is not looking great, you can sell buildings you don't need to balance it back out.

Science is the method by which you gain technology.  It's represented by a blue beaker.  You'll earn it by:

- Establishing trade routes, especially with other Civs, but also frequently from stations
- Building certain tile improvements (the Academy, primarily)
- Creating buildings in your cities, mostly related to science or research
- Launching orbital units, such as the Lasercom Satellite or the Deep Space Telescope
- Certain virtues boost it, mainly those in the Knowledge tree, although you can also produce a bunch if you take the "killing aliens grants science" virtue from the Might tree
- Producing science in your cities will convert a portion of that city's production to science
- Stealing it via espionage from other civs, this is another relatively easy espionage operation

Buildings can also have a special modifier that you choose via quests.  Many of these will change the science or energy output of a building.  Note that choosing "free maintenance" is functionally similar to "+X energy" for most buildings.

Science and energy output are also modified by difficulty, so taking the difficulty down will make you produce more per turn than players or AI at other difficulty levels.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the research window there is a drop down box in the top left. Here you can filter technologies for what you need. You can choose to filter by science, energy, health etc... This will help you unlock building and upgrades specifically for what you require.

You can then build the buildings and tile improvements to increase what you need.

Another method of getting more energy is by building a solar collector and launching it over one of your cities.

Likewise a laser com satellite will provide a research boost on the cities in its range.

You can also try to trade for energy or demand it from other leaders.

Demanding will only really work if they fear you.

Once you get spies you can attempt to steal both science and energy from other colonies. This will impact your relationship with the colony negatively if caught though.

Some virtues also give you bonuses in these areas.

Another method to get science and energy is by trading. To get your first two trade slots for a city you need the trade depot. You can then set up trade routes with other colonies to get science and energy.